# Writing to a 2D Array via Pointer Notation

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, gcc, lvalue

I'm having trouble understanding why incrementing the pointers in pnArryCpy below is incorrect. I figured out how to copy the array using pointer notation a different way, but I need to understand what's wrong with this (e.g., `(* tgt_s)++;` where `int (*tgt_s)[cs]`),  and why `tgt_s` is an lvalue (e.g., `tgt_s++` is valid) but `*tgt_s` *is not* (really) an lvalue.

```
int main(void)
{

    int arr1[2][4] = { {1, 2, 3, 4}, {6, 7, 8, 9} }; 
    int arr2[2][4];                             

    pnArrCpy(4, arr1, arr2, arr2+2); // copies 2d array using pointer notation 
                                     // - this is where the problem is.
    printarr(2, 4, arr2); // this just prints the array and works fine - not at issue

    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}

void pnArrCpy(int cs, int (*src)[cs], int (*tgt_s)[cs], int (*tgt_e)[cs])
{
    while (tgt_s < tgt_e)
    {

        **tgt_s=**src;  
        (* tgt_s)++; // older versions of gcc warn "target of assignment not really
                     // an lvalue", latest versions throw an error
        (* src)++;   // but no errors are runtime

    }

    return;
}

// trucated rest of program since it's not relevant, just the function for printing
// the array
```

Under the older gcc, the program compiles and displays the correct results, namely:

```
1 2 3 4 
6 7 8 9
```

Mac OS 10.8.2
gcc 4.7.2 gave me the error
gcc 4.2.1 was only giving me warnings

Thank you!!

EDIT: Reason I'm using variable length arrays: this function is part of another program, and this one is just a driver I was using to troubleshoot pnArrCpy. In the actual program, the array dimensions and contents are user defined, hence use of VLA.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is:

- `int (*tgt_s)[cs]` is a **pointer to an array**. Take a few seconds to think about that, it's a bit of an exotic pointer
- `*tgt_s` is therefore an array
- arrays are not modifiable lvalues

What makes it hardest to understand is the way you're using the C99 feature of passing `cs` and then using it in the parameter list.

If you want to learn more about VLAs as function arguments, check out [this excellent post](http://gustedt.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/vla-as-function-arguments/).

Comment: @H2CO3 Using `cs` in the paremeter list is C99. I linked a post by Jens Gustedt.

Comment: I mean how did the compiler permit to increment an array.

Comment: @H2CO3 You mean the old 4.2.1 ? I don't know.

Comment: I must have confused myself with how arrays sometimes decay into pointers, and that the array name without brackets is a pointer to its first element.

I think my train of thought was: tgt_s is a pointer to an array of arrays, and each array (in the array of arrays) has a pointer to its first element (which can be incremented to the second, etc.) -- and this is how it seems to have worked. Is that why it worked? (Need to think this over in the morning.)

Comment: @H2CO3 its still a pointer, and as such you can certainly increment it. It should leap by the underlying base size, which as it turns out is based on `sizeof(**ar)*cs` [See it live](http://ideone.com/8KE1RK), and note the address differences after the increments.

Comment: @WhozCraig Interesting - I always thought only the first level of indirection decays into a pointer, further ones don't.

Comment: @H2CO3 That's correct. In the example posted by WhozCraig he increments `ar` which is a pointer, **not `*ar`**, which would elicit the same error the OP is getting.

Comment: @H2CO3 You're correct in your thought. It is that reason that causes the increment to leap as it does, in the first case in my example, by 40 bytes (10 ints), in the second case, by 20 bytes (5 ints). cnicutar  noted that the pointer, not the underlying array, is incremented in that sample, and just like `int * p; ++p;` will vault the pointer by sizeof(int) bytes, so shall doing so with an array pointer by the underlying dimension sized to its elements. IOW, you're right.

Comment: @cnicutar and WhozCraig Thanks. I'm glad I wasn't wrong. Maybe I just have to read the code before complaining about it ;-)

Comment: @H2CO3 You're not the only one; that sample proved something the OP was *not* doing was okeedokee (durp!). =P

Comment: @WhozCraig Yup :) I remember somebody on SO mentioning the "StackOverflow rule of thumb #1: if OP says he knows it, he doesn't" :P

Comment: +1 in all the noise I totally neglected to notice that cnicutar's answer is quite-correct =)